# I want to show background-image in full screen

Tags: html, css, background, width, background-image

My question is about "background-image" in CSS. How can I add "background-image" in full screen? I used "width: 100% " but it doesn't work.

Comment: `background-size` property?

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,body{
 height: 100%;
}
body{ 
 background-image:url(http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/s-Yoshi-The-Seal-Kitteh.jpg);
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat:  no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size:  cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
     body {
     background: url(http://i.imgur.com/aZO5Kolb.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
}
     html {
      height: 100%
     }
```